# How to disable menu cart link from woocommerce but retain click fucntionality

Tags: javascript, php, css, woocommerce, cart

How can i disable the link itself from cart in the menu. This is Woocommerce. Disabling with css doesnt work, because I need click funciotnality with another plugin. I did try with css and it didnt solve the problem. Im not so good at coding with javascript, but Ive heard that it might be the solution.

I think it's this action/function that need to be removed:

```
function get_cart_url() {
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_cart_url', wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) );
        return wc_get_cart_url();
    }
```

Comment: Try to inspect it in browser, than copy over the relevant HTML code here, so we can see it.

Comment: <a href="https://xn--tybleier-54a.no" class="cart-contents shopping-bag " title="View your shopping cart"><span class="number-of-items no-items"></span><span class="amount"></span></a>

Comment: But its native to woocommerce, so there should be some snippet to do it? Like some filter to disable the minicart link